# Didn't Imperial officers (or the general public) know that the Emperor was a Sith?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

In Episode IV, everyone seems to believe that Vader is the only one left who can use the Force.

> **Tarkin:** The Jedi are extinct. Their fire has gone out of the universe. You, my friend, are all that's left of their religion.

Of course, they thought the Jedi were all killed, but what about the Emperor?

I realize that he is not even mentioned in Episode IV, so did nobody know that he was a Sith? Or is it just the fact that he was not intended to be brought up in the movie at that point?

Comment: he never announce nor showed the public that he could use the force, so only the remaining jedi, and a few others knew. afaik.

Comment: @phantom42 - Based on the linked question, that admits that a few close people would know about his Sith identity, in case of Admiral Tarkin, being a high rank, one of Palpatine's favorite man, shouldn't he know?

Comment: *Grand Moff* Tarkin. And Jedi != Sith. Vader used to be a Jedi so in that sense he's "all that's left", but he's a Sith now.

Comment: Tarkin is a high ranking politician, but I don't remember anything G-canon that puts him as being within Papaltine's "inner circle", so to speak. FWIW: I don't know that BBlake's answer to the other question is necessarily *correct*, but this subject has come up already.

Comment: @Null - Actually, *All Mighty* Tarkin talks about their *religion*. Earlier in the episode, the other officer that I don't remember the name, say that Vader is still devoted to this *sad religion*... So he means the Force, not actually light side Jedi...

Comment: Palpatine might *especially* want to conceal his Force powers from his close associates, unless there was some reason why they really had to know. Being able to sense lies and read their emotions (without them knowing he could) would be extremely useful, for instance if they were concealing bad news or plotting against him.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit - I believe this would be a great answer to the linked question - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9907/why-didnt-palpatine-publicly-change-his-name-once-he-became-emperor