# Why did Tarkin say that Vader was the last of the religion of the Force?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, a-new-hope

In *Episode IV*, Tarkin says to Vader:

> The Jedi are extinct, their fire has gone out of the universe.  You, my friend, are all that's left of their religion

This struck me quite a bit, because the question arises that if Vader is part of 'their religion', then surely the Emperor is also.  My question is then, **why did Tarkin say that Vader was all that was left of the 'religion' of the Force, when Emperor Palpantine would equally be part of that religion?**

Comment: Hmmm, I never got the impression that the emperor's identity as a force user was known to other imperials (outside a select few if any).

Comment: @RedCaio If evidence of that could be found, that would make for a good explanation!

Comment: Well, there is this (kind of related): http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/92291/30726 (the whole question deals with it, but the quote from the book *Tarkin* given in this answer probably fits best)

Comment: @BMWurm Yes, that answers the question then!

Comment: Not quite the same thing IMO.  But this question is easily answered: Palpatine was not a Jedi, not even a fallen Jedi.  Tarkin explicitly said that the *Jedi* were extinct, that Vader was the last Jedi - not that Vader was the last person able to use the Force.