# What were Darth Vader's day-to-day tasks/duties?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, darth-vader

Vader's role in the Empire/Imperial Forces was already discussed multiple times ([here for example](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114758/what-was-darth-vaders-official-role-or-rank-in-the-empire)).

I understand that he has a special role, not comparable to any position in real world military and he primarily executed special tasks given by the emperor, like finding the rebel base, capturing Luke and so on.

But I asked myself what his day-to-day tasks were. Are there any canon sources (Legends would be fine for me, too) what he did on a day to day basis? Did he have administrative tasks or something of the like? I find it hard to believe all he did was meditating or standing on the bridge of a ship being bad-ass, when there weren't any urgent tasks (things we see him do in the movies)

Trying to be more specific:

- What did he do after he arrived on the Death Star 2 until the Emperor and later the Rebels showed up?
- What did he do during the time after the first Death Star was destroyed (his primary task seemed to be finding the rebel base, but again, I can hardly imagining him always standing on a bridge and giving orders like "Ok, go there, fly this way")

Are there any information on this topic?

Comment: Are you seriously asking for his job description? I wonder if there's a copy of his contract of employment somewhere? :)

Comment: [He does some paperwork](https://s1.ibtimes.com/sites/www.ibtimes.com/files/styles/lg/public/2011/11/19/192887-darth-vader.jpg), [gives seminars](http://c0.thejournal.ie/media/2014/04/darthvaderukraine-390x285.png), [a splash of public speaking](https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2014/04/04/11/ukraine-2.jpg) and [hands out fliers](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-XC_QXeV0D_8/Uziml5-J_5I/AAAAAAAAEkk/iotrj3M26wY/s1600/PrezVader.jpg).

Comment: Well, in some way I do =) I thinks it's interesting. But to be honest, there were more far fetched questions asked here, that were answered in incredible detail, one thing that amazes me about this community here =)

Comment: And I'm not asking about his free time, we even have pictures of that:
https://www.boredpanda.com/365-photography-project-daily-life-darth-vader-pawel-kadysz

Comment: Hunting down and killing Jedi

Comment: Being a good father...

Comment: Whatever keeps him busy enough to stop him from overthrowing his master and taking his own apprentice. Largely paperwork that could have been automated.

Comment: Basically beginning at the end of Revenge of the Sith, he has the open-ended task of detecting and crushing all resistance.  On the scale of a galaxy-spanning empire, that's a pretty big task.  If you were given that task, how would you begin?  Gather intelligence, create plans, identify resources, recruit team members - it's basically the largest PMO job ever given out.  He'd keep busy.

Comment: Bringing balance to the Force, obviously.

Comment: The new canon comics series get into some of his non-film exploits

Comment: @GrahamLee, I'm not sure what he does, but in the GFFA I'm pretty sure it can't be **paper**work.

Comment: He managed a grocery store.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wGR4-SeuJ0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Vader didn't have daily routine

In Canon, life of Vader is now described in two comics series : [Star Wars:Darth Vader](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Darth_Vader_(Marvel)) and [Star Wars: Darth Vader: Dark Lord of the Sith](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Darth_Vader:_Dark_Lord_of_the_Sith). Without mentioning details, Vader was task-oriented. Those tasks would (of course) mostly came from his master Palpatine. Sometimes he had to work alone, sometimes in small groups, sometimes he commanded fleets and armies ... 
Palpatine often tested him by pitting him against other Imperials, Vader  tried to clandestinely work for his own interests, but Palpatine mostly foresaw this. Vader acted according to Palpatine's plans even if he didn't know that (this is one of the reasons Vader feared and respected Palpatine). Vader did have some time for himself (for example to build his castle on Mustafar), and this is he used to better understand Dark Side of the Force.

Overall, Vader was not tied to specific unit, system or Galactic Sector, so he didn't regularly attend boring administrative meetings if they didn't concern his current mission.

Answer (score 1):

Shadows of the Empire, Legends canon-imo best canon. Has Vader doing his daily activities of running the Empire. He practiced with battle droids of various levels of ability and speed, even upgrading to 2 at once, but mentioning Luke was the only real fun he had. He also practiced healing his scarred tissue, keeping time outside of a stasis unit as long as he could hold it. This story takes place after empire and before jedi.

He had various meetings with Imperials as well as Criminal organizations, discussing troop movements or shipping orders. He was also tasked with specific missions deemed more important by the Emperor, such as the destruction of a rebel shipyard, leading the attack and even going into his own ship for some dogfights for the fun of it...then gets bored.

Part of the fun of the book was reading about the various activities and thoughts of both Vader(such as how he hated spies) and Xizor(who loved spies), the real antagonist of the book.

Answer (score 0):

As a high force in the Empire, he most likely had many boring day to day tasks that Lucasfilm does not bother showing us. One of these scenes is on the Death Star, when he is attending the board room meeting and terrorizing the poor workers. He just attends meetings, and reports his progress to the Emperor, as shown throughout the movies. He reports down to exterminate Rebel Forces spread out and about the galaxy, as on Cloud City. His day to day life is not very exciting, as most people's life's are.

Comment: Do you have any sources or evidence you can link to that supports your theory?

Comment: No but we have evidence from the movies

Comment: Ok - To help boost your answer can you include the specific examples from the movies that you’re drawing from?

Comment: i did use the examples