# Was Count Dooku a Sith?

Tags: star-wars

A friend of mine said that Count Dooku only was a good friend of the Sith. I think that Count Dooku is a Sith.

So was Count Dooku a Sith?

Is there any evidence of him being a Sith?

Comment: In no way is this question "unclear what you are asking", close voters.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Sci-Fi stackechange. Have you taken the [tour]? We need to know more about your question and why it's not obvious to you that Dooku, also know as [Darth Tyranus](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dooku) is not a sith.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? Not everyone who's seen the movie will remember the brief lines about Darth Tyranus, so I think it's a good question. After all, not every lightsaber-wielding ally of Darth Sidious was a Sith, as evidenced by General Grievous.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - I myself didn't vote; but probably because the question shows incredibly little research effort (like, a basic Google search and Wiki page listed as one of first 3 results would provide a clear answer). That's considered one of the actually legit reasons to downvote.

Comment: @DVK - You could say the same about [this question about the location of Hill Valley in Back to the Future](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105102/where-is-hill-valley), which is directly answered by a line in the movie, and is also mentioned as being in California on its [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_Valley_(Back_to_the_Future)), yet that question got 79 upvotes. Besides, although the wookieepedia article (and wikipedia article) on Count Dooku say he was also known as Darth Tyranus, they don't cite specific movie lines.

Comment: @DVK - I'd say it's a major plot point that he was a darksider working for Darth Sidious, but not that his title was Darth Tyranus, as he was only called Tyranus twice, once without "Darth" (the line from Yoda in NikolaiDante's post wasn't in the film). If the criticism is that this is easy to find by googling, then you could say the same thing about Hill Valley's location despite it not being an important plot point, since if you google Hill Valley the wikipedia article is the first thing that comes up, and the first line of that article is "Hill Valley, California, is a fictional town ..."

Comment: Also, as just pointed out by vynsane in an [answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/108667/22250) to another question about this, in the filmed version Jango just refers to him as a "man called Tyranus" without the "Darth", so there are *no* references to "Darth" Tyranus anywhere in the movie. I'd say that's all the more reason to see this as a reasonable question that one might ask even if one payed very close attention to the dialogue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is confirmed during *Star Wars: Episode II: Attack of the Clones*...

When Obi-Wan confronts Jango Fett:

> **OBI-WAN**: Sifo-Dyas. Isn’t he the Jedi who hired you for this job?
>   **JANGO**: Never heard of him. I was recuited by a man called ***Darth Tyranus*** on one of the moons of Bogden.

And at the end of the film:

> **Count Dooku**: The force is with us, Master Sidious.
>   **Darth Sidious**: Welcome home ***Lord Tyranus***. You have done well.

Yoda confirms that with a prefix of Darth, that makes him a Sith:

> **OBI-WAN**: One more thing. Jango mentioned he was recruited by someone named Darth Tyranus. Any idea who that might be?
>   **YODA**: With the forename ***Darth, a Sith he must be***.

Quotes sourced from [imsdb](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Attack-of-the-Clones.html).

Comment: The line from Yoda appears in that script in a scene right after the death of Shmi, but if you watch the scene after Shmi's death (and Anakin's freakout) in the movie, it's a private conference between Mace Windu and Yoda, not a conference with Obi-Wan as in the script, and so Yoda isn't shown learning of the name "Darth Tyranus".

Answer (score 1):

yes, he is a Dark Lord of the Sith, known as Darth Tyranus.